# And condition with if

Tags: shell

```
num1 =0
num2 =0
```

I want to print OK if both num1 and num2 are 0 in a single if statement.

Answer (score 4):

In POSIX shell you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $num1 -eq 0 -a $num2 -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "ok"
fi
```

If you can use `bash` then you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( num1 == 0 && num2 == 0)); then
  echo "ok"
fi
```

If you want to save keystrokes and don't mind being a bit cryptic you could also do:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! (( num1 | num2 )); then
  echo "ok"
fi
```

Comment: Also, one can call "test" twice: `if [[ $num -eq 0 ]] && [[ $num -eq 0 ]]; then ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use case/esac without worrying about different styles of if/else

```
case "$num1$num2" in
 "00" ) echo "ok";;
 * ) echo "not ok";;
esac
```